# Power Automate flow cannot display ADE graph query

Tags: power-automate, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have this Power Automate flow:
[Flow rendering a time chart then sending email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft1y7.png)

It uses the action "Run KQL query and render a chart" and runs an ADE query I have made already which renders a timechart with this kql syntax:
...| render timechart with (title = "Title");

This timechart has a couple of data lines in it over time.

After running this ADE function, I put the only option for the above action, the BodyHtml, into the body of the action "Send an email (V2)".

However, when I receive the email, all I see is a broken image stating "This linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved..."
[The image cannot be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UArOI.png)

**How can I include a graph output from an ADE function in an email in Power Automate?**

I have also tried putting the image in the email with html format turned on, but I receive the same result.

Comment: Could you add an image with your "Send an Email" action expanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try adding the chart as an attachment.

see documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/flow-usage#email-multiple-azure-data-explorer-flow-charts

and example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/flow-usage#email-multiple-azure-data-explorer-flow-charts